# Adding Order Clause to GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql

How can I modify the following so that it displays place names (GG.Name) alphabetically?

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<a href=\"', GG.URL, '\" title=\"', GG.Name, '\">', GG.Name, '</a>')) AS Names,
```

My original GROUP_CONCAT clause included "ORDER BY", but I can't make it work with my revised code.

Also, do you know how I can modify it so that there's a space after each comma? It displays Arizona,California,Texas. I've actually fixed it with a simple str_replace function, but I just wondered if there's a way to make it display correctly without that fix.

**EDIT:**

I tried both of the following variations, but they both produce syntax errors...

```
SELECT PLAN.Latin Latin2, PLAN.Common, PLAN.Rank, PLAN.Planimal, PLAN.Family, PLAN.Order1, PLAN.NoSymbol, PLAN.National, GS.Symbol, GS.Latin, GG.URL AS GURL, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<a href=\"', GG.URL, '\" title=\"', GG.Name, '\">', GG.Name, '</a>' ORDER BY GG.Name SEPARATE ',  ')) AS Names, GG.IDParent
FROM gs_planimals PLAN
LEFT JOIN gs GS ON GS.Latin = PLAN.Latin
LEFT JOIN gw_geog GG ON GG.IDArea = GS.IDArea AND GG.IDParent = :DBParent
WHERE Rank != 55 AND PLAN.National = 'nat' AND NoSymbol != '1'
GROUP BY PLAN.Latin
ORDER BY PLAN.N, GG.Name
```

Version #2:

```
SELECT PLAN.Latin Latin2, PLAN.Common, PLAN.Rank, PLAN.Planimal, PLAN.Family, PLAN.Order1, PLAN.NoSymbol, PLAN.National, GS.Symbol, GS.Latin, GG.URL AS GURL, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<a href=\"', GG.URL, '\" title=\"', GG.Name, '\">', GG.Name, '</a>') ORDER BY GG.Name SEPARATE ', ') AS Names, GG.IDParent
FROM gs_planimals PLAN
LEFT JOIN gs GS ON GS.Latin = PLAN.Latin
LEFT JOIN gw_geog GG ON GG.IDArea = GS.IDArea AND GG.IDParent = :DBParent
WHERE Rank != 55 AND PLAN.National = 'nat' AND NoSymbol != '1'
GROUP BY PLAN.Latin
ORDER BY PLAN.N, GG.Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is well [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).  As a note, you don't even need the `concat()` because `group_concat()` can take multiple arguments.  So, if I understand correctly:

```
GROUP_CONCAT('<a href=\"', GG.URL, '\" title=\"', GG.Name, '\">', GG.Name, '</a>'
              ORDER BY GC.Name SEPARATOR ', ') AS Names,
```

Comment: Hmmm...that's similar to what I tried earlier. I edited my original post, adding two variations I tried without success (syntax errors). I also tried the same two variations deleting CONCAT (and the extra parentheses), with the same results.